# my App Store is broken for Mac High Sierra 10.13.5 please help

Tags: mac-appstore

[image]

I will click featured or something else and it automatically redirects me to updates it is making me mad someone please help me out thanks I appreciate it

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: yeah but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Have you tried restarting into safe mode?